# jquery selector and Objects selection

Tags: jquery-selectors

typically when you refer to an object you would use a selector like this :

```
$(this).jqueryfunction()
```

if u would need an element within this object you would use :

```
$('typicalselector',this).jqueryfunction()
```

My question is how would I use jquery selector to select various objects something along the lines of :

```
($(this.fistobject) and $(this.secondObject)).jqueryfunction()
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrap an object or run a selector, you get a set or collection. So this would return a collection and then [add](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/add) another collection to it, and then perform jqueryfunction() to the combined set:

```
$('someSelector').add('anotherSelector').jqueryfunction()
```

This works with contexts, too.

Comment: This works .
 is there a way to do it in the same selector like this :

$(this.one and this.otherone).jqueryfunction() ? (this.one and this.otherone are both javascript objects by the way)

Comment: What kind of JS objects? Post some more code. If they can be wrapped with a $(), then you can do this: `$(obj1).add(obj2).jqueryfunction` or if that doesn't work, then this should: `$(obj1).add($(obj2)).jqueryfunction`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comma, just like in CSS. I.e.

```
$('div, a', this)
```

would select all div and a elements in 'this'.

I dont think you can work jQuery on Javascript objects, they should be jQuery-wrapped HTML Elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple selectors like this:

```
$(selector1, selector2, ..., selectorn).jqueryfunction();
```